# Selenium Python - selecting from a list on the web with no stored/embedded options

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python so forgive me if this isn't completely comprehensible. I'm trying to select from a combobox in a webpage. All the examples I've seen online are choosing from a list where the options are embedded within the code. I believe my issue is that the list I'm dealing with does not. The list is dynamic and the values are stored in a table.

So using the Select class method I keep getting the "Select only works on select elements, not on input" when using a command like this

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sppProcessForm']/div[1]/form/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/span/input")).select_by_value('Q2-2018 Q2 GUIDANCE')
```

I get the unable to locate an element error when trying to use the Option method.

Here is the source code for the combobox along with the dropdown button. As you can see, no list options. I also just started learning about HTML so not sure how all that works.

```
<span class="custom-combobox">
    <input title="" class="custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
<a tabindex="-1" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-button-icon-only custom-anchor custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" role="button">
<span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">
    </span><span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span></a></span>
    <span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>
```

Comment: Can you show us the rendered html. Remove the uncluttered code, and show us just the table...

Comment: @fazkan added. Let me know if that doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is Possible to build **drop down** without using **Select** and **Options** tag which is available in **HTML**.

**pseudocode** :

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("your xpath for drop down")
```

loop to iterate over this list

Inside loop if condition for a webelement like :  `webElement.getText().equals(" your value from drop down")`

click on the element like `element.click()`

closure of if followed by closer of loop.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Select only works on select elements, not on input
```

...implies that you have initialized a `Select` object and tried to pass an *input* tag to the `Select` object.

As per the HTML you have shared the desired object is within an `<input>` tag. So you can't assign the *input* tag to a *Select* instance. Instead to click and expand the *selection box* you can try the following code block :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='custom-combobox']/input[@class='custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left ui-autocomplete-input']")
```

Comment: Thanks that does find the element, but if I'm trying to select the text "Q2-2018 Q2 GUIDANCE" how would I do that?

Comment: @Wells To select the text **Q2-2018 Q2 GUIDANCE** you need to provide us with the relevant HTML and raise a new question with your new requirement. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Isn't selecting that text a part of this question lol? And what is the relevant HTML? What I supplied is the full code related to that ComboBox. Lead me in the right direction and I'll give you the thumbs up.

Comment: @Wells The element with text as **Q2-2018 Q2 GUIDANCE** is not present within the HTML you have provided within the question. You need to provide us the HTML related to the option with text **Q2-2018 Q2 GUIDANCE** in a seperate question to construct a good answer.